# SSIS 2008 with Stored Procedures. Transaction best practices

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, ssis

I'm currenlty using SSIS for some process flow, scripting, and straight data import.  Most of the data cleaning and transformation is happening within stored procedures that I'm calling from SSIS execute SQL tasks.  For most of the sprocs, if it fails for any reason, I don't really care about rolling back any transactions.  My SSIS error handling essentially wipes out any staging data and then logs the errors to a table.  (A human needs to fix the underlying data issue at that point)

My question revolves around begin tran, end tran.  Are there any cases where a stored proc can fail, and then not let the calling SSIS process know?  I'm looking for hardware failure, lock timeouts, etc.

I'd prefer to avoid using transactions as much as possible and rely on my SSIS error handling.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once case I can think of (and transactions won't help either) would be if the stored proc did not update or insert any records. That would not be a failure, but it might need to be for an SSIS package. You might want to return how many rows were affected and check that after.

We also do this for some imports where a number significantly off from the last import indicates a data problem. So if we usually get 100,000 records from client A in Import B and we get 5000 instead, the SSIS package fails until a human can look at it and see it the file is bad or if they genuiinely did mean to reduce their work force or customer list.

Incidentally we stage to two tables (one with the raw unchanged data and one we use for cleaning. A failure of the SSIS package should not roll those back if you want to easily see what the data issues was. You can then tell if the data was wrong from the start or if somehow it got lost or fixed incorrectly inteh cleaning process. Sometimes the place where the error got logged is not the place where the error actually occurred and it is nice to see what the data looked like unchanged and after the change process. Sometimes you have bad data, yes (Ok the majority of times) but sometimes you have a bug. Having both those tables enables you to uickly see which of the two it is.

You could have all your procs insert to a logging table as the last step and make sure that the record is there before executing the next step if you are concerned that you are losing some executions that are not bubbling back to the package.

Comment: Great points.  I'm actually looking at the update and insert counts as well.  I'm also not keeping the raw unchanged data in SQL server, but am logging the actual row number of the problematic file.  That way, you don't need to look in SQL to see what the problem is.

Comment: Well I have files with over a million records, it is usually easier to query a table to find the problem records. But we log the exact line number as well.

Comment: I understand.  Our files are more in line of 20K records.  The analysts basically use excel to open and review the files.